# Dynamically setup aoColumnDefs for datatables

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, datatables

My datatable is getting displayed in partial view in `ASP.NET MVC`. on display it actually fetch up the data from database based on certain condition that result in different column numbers with their data.

Not only this the column names are dynamically fetched and displayed. I am able to do if I have a fixed columns numbers by providing first the table structure in a loop for all columns and data and then at end setup the initialization of datatables with fixed `aoColumnDefs` values to hide certain columns at startup.

Now on another action, it calls the controller action to fetch another set of data with the different column counts (decreased for example_ and here I am facing issue how to setup it as it is fixed initially).

This result in break of (loss of columns that was setup) and hence datatables binding looks failed and now the table is no more showing datatables properties setup initially. Because say column number `7` to `10` that was hidden using `aoColumnDefs`, now the current set has only say `5` columns to display. This result in break of datatables attributes that were setup.

Can I kind of reinitialize those datatables attributes for new set of columns? What should be the good if not best approach but yet easy.

Comment: you could have use datatable HTML(DOM) source mode to make this possible with easy steps, For this you should create the table according to you values and then render the plugin based on that table. you can refer this link http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html

Comment: @ Frebin, yes the provided link is the basic one but it is just simple initialization for the table and set it to datatable. I need to apply datatable attributes like sorting on particular column by default (this will be different for different views). In html dom i just iterate through the model.items to create the table but their is no way to specify the sorting column.